# How to structure complex wizard form

Tags: forms, design-process, wizard

I have a complex form am modelling using Wizard pattern and this is the flow of the form.

1. Add a organization supply information, how many items were delivered and how many were used.
2. after that, you can either sign off or add each child organization supply info.

my current solution:

1. Add organization information.
2. Preview, then present option to sign off or add child organization info at preview screen.
3. if Child Organization is selected, then have "Add another Child info" and a Finish button at the screen.
4. The finish button completes the "Add Child Organization Info"

my challenges are:

1. Should i show the users list of organizations they have been added in a table view just above the Add form or
2. Just have Add form and next add form validates, add the content to list and clears the form for new entry.
3. Should i just have the form in 2 above, without list view of added organizations, then on finish present a table of CFs added with option to remove and then final sign off.

[image]

Comment: I think the solution should be based on a combination of business, technical and user requirements, at least from the information presented here.